# Unexpected token ) in in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am watching a tutorial from the new boston and I have check line by line and I can't see how my code is different. I am getting an unexpected token ) error in this page.

When I delete the ) after the item in fucntion(item) within the foreach then it says unexpected token {. So I'm not sure where to go from this point. Am I missing something small?

EDIT: I am adding the error I get on the page here in the code since its to long to put for a comment.

EDIT2: Added header.ejs

header.ejs

```
<a href="/">Home</a> |
<a href="/about">About</a> |
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
```

---

```
Unexpected token ) in c:\Users\Amazo\WebstormProjects\Project1Express\views\index.ejs while compiling ejs

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) in c:\Users\Amazo\WebstormProjects\Project1Express\views\index.ejs while compiling ejs
    at Function (native)
    at Object.Template.compile (c:\Users\Amazo\WebstormProjects\Project1Express\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:464:12)
    at Object.compile (c:\Users\Amazo\WebstormProjects\Project1Express\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:288:16)
    at handleCache (c:\Users\Amazo\WebstormProjects\Project1Express\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:147:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (c:\Users\Amazo\WebstormProjects\Project1Express\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:350:14)
    at View.render (c:\Users\Amazo\WebstormProjects\Project1Express\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
    at tryRender (c:\Users\Amazo\WebstormProjects\Project1Express\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (c:\Users\Amazo\WebstormProjects\Project1Express\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:591:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (c:\Users\Amazo\WebstormProjects\Project1Express\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
    at c:\Users\Amazo\WebstormProjects\Project1Express\routes\index.js:6:7
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>

  <% include templates/header.ejs %>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <h1><%= points %></h1>
  <h3><%= videodata.categoryName %></h3>
  <p>My name is <%= name %> and I am <%= age %> years old. My occupation is being a <%= occupation %>.</p>
  <ul>
    <%= videodata.categories.forEach(function(item) {  %>
      <li><% item.categoryName %></li>
    <% }); %>
  </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On what line is the error?

Comment: I added the error I get into the post. It doesn't say what line it is on.

Comment: @torazaburo   It is added

Comment: As to "I can't see how my code is different": There's code available to compare two sets of code. There's one for the jEdit editor (uses Java); the plug-in is JDiff. There's one that comes with Tortoise SVN. I'm sure there are others.

Comment: If his code is on a youtube video I'm not sure how that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are using echo (`<%=`) on your loop (`forEach`) but not for the output each time through the loop (`item.categoryName`):

```
<%= videodata.categories.forEach(function(item) {  %>
  <li><% item.categoryName %></li>
<% }); %>
```

I think you should swap those, so you are using `<%=` in the item, not on the loop.

```
<% videodata.categories.forEach(function(item) {  %>
  <li><%= item.categoryName %></li>
<% }); %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved :

```
<% videodata.categories.forEach(function(item) {  %>
  <li><%= item.categoryName %></li>
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot "=" in the following string:

```
 <li><%= item.categoryName %></li>
```